# how to evaluate $\sum_{r=0}^{10} \frac{{10 \choose r}}{{30 \choose 10+r}}$

Tags: summation, combinations

$$\sum_{r=0}^{10} \frac{{10 \choose r}}{{30 \choose 10+r}}$$

I used properties of "choose" and simplified it into numerator only.

$$\frac{1}{{30\choose 20}{20 \choose 10}} \sum_{r=0}^{10} {10+r \choose r}{20-r \choose 10}$$

But I am confused how to proceed furthur.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a sequence of $10$ distinct numbers $1\le x_1<x_2\ldots<x_{10}\le31$ from the set $\{1,\ldots,31\}$. Call the *rank* of this sequence the largest integer $r\in\{0,\ldots,10\}$ such that $x_1,\ldots,x_r\le10+r$: $$1\le x_1<\cdots<x_r\le 10+r<x_{r+1}<\ldots<x_{10}\le31.$$(If $x_1\ge11$, then $r=0$, and if $x_{10}\le20$, then $r=10$.) Note that $x_{r+1}\neq10+r+1$ by maximality of $r$.
Thus the other $10-r$ numbers $x_{r+1},\ldots,x_{10}$ are of the form $10+r+1+x$ for $x\in\{1,\ldots,20-r\}$. That makes $$\binom{10+r}{r}\binom{20-r}{10-r}=\binom{10+r}{10}\binom{20-r}{10}$$ combinations with rank $r$. Summing over every possible rank $r\in\{0,\ldots,10\}$ then gives $$\sum_{r=0}^{10}\binom{10+r}{r}\binom{20-r}{10}=\binom{31}{10}.$$

Comment: That was amazing answer! thankyou

Answer (score 2):

> An algebraic variation: We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^{10}}\color{blue}{\binom{10+r}{r}\binom{20-r}{10}}
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{10}\binom{10+r}{r}\binom{20-r}{10-r}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{10}\binom{-11}{r}\binom{-11}{10-r}\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{-22}{10}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{31}{10}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the other answer.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we use the identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ and note that $(-1)^r\cdot(-1)^{10-r}=1$.
- In (3) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.
- In (4) we use again the identity as in (2).

*Note:* We can extend the definition of *binomial coefficients* beyond its combinatorial meaning and use negative (even complex) numbers as upper index. See e.g. *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097947/is-it-valid-to-define-binomnnk-0/3099216#3099216)* for more information.

Comment: Is $n\choose r$ defined for negative numbers ?

Comment: @ShlokJain: Yes, it's also defined for negative numbers. I've added a note which might be helpful.